# Determine a cause of privilege elevation in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I've stuck with some problem in my Visual Studio instance. I've used it for a while with the low-priveleged user account without any problem. But today I found that I can't start it without administrative account. I don't know what was happened but it seems that it is incurred by some plugin I've installed recently.
So I need to find what the part of the Visual Studio startup process requires the privilege elevation or at least what the privilege cause the UAC to be invoked.
I don't want to use VS with admin account.

System info:
Windows 7 Ultimate, Visual Studio 2010 SP1. VS is used with C++ only and didn't demand rights evaluation before.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be of any use. But for the record if you're writing Web Projects is VS, and use IIS for debugging (rather than IISExpress or Cassini) you need to run as Admin - however I think VS is pretty verbose about this, so you should have noticed if this was the cause.

Comment: No, I don't use Web Project. C++ only.